# Ionic 3: Deeplink using Universal Link on iOS not opening app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, deep-linking

I've got this problem I can't figure out, so hopefully somebody else can.
Deeplink using Univerval Linking opens website, not the app on iOS.

I'm using Ionic 3 with plugin ionic-plugin-deeplinks.
In my config.xml there's the following:

```
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="test.domain.com" />
```

In my webroot/.well-known dir I have an apple-app-site-association file:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "******.com.domain.test",
            "paths": [ "/subdir/test1", "/subdir/test1/"]
        }
    ]}
}
```

Now, the custom deeplink is working (using myapp://test.domain.com/subdir/test1), but the Universal Link is not (using https://test.domain.com/subdir/test1).

I just don't know what to do anymore...
Can anybody help me?

Note: I have set the associated-domains to: applinks:test.domain.com

Comment: Did you find an answer since then?

Answer (score 0):

Did subscribe the URL in your angular application? 
And one more thing, allow all the url's in apple-app-site-association file just to make it works. After that u can restrict them

```
"paths": ["/*"]
```

And double check the prefix of your app name.
Also if you look at this destination

```
Project -> platform -> ios -> projectName -> Entitlements-Debug.plist
```

you will notice the domain that you add in Associated domains, but in Entitlements-Release.plist is not. Add them to look like the develop one.
To work in Test Flight you need to add it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

It works for me if I remove this line:

`<variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp" />`